# ILIAS 6.7 Database can't be reached

Tags: database, ilias

I'm trying to setup ILIAS on a fresh Debian Buster install with apache + php 7.3 + mariadb + composer 1.9.3.
I have passed preliminary & Basic Settings from web UI but when I try to create a new client I got this error:

'''
-Database can't be reached. Please check the credentials and if database exists-
'''

I had try both MyISAM & InnoDB version of MySQL but with the same issue.
I've google a couple of days before posting here, I've already read related post both on here and other places but with no luck at all.
Anyone could help me to finish my installation?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I've rebooted the VM and it start working, don't ask me why...